# Can HTML comment tags be rendered, for a description as an example

Tags: html

I am trying to pick up some HTML and I am using HTML to write my notes as I go along.  Can I include the comment brackets in a way that they will be a part of the displayed output?

As an example that is not working,

```
<p>To enter comments or notes that are visible to anyone inspecting the source code but that will not be rendered, place your notes between the comment brackets <!-- notes --></p>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `&lt;!-- notes --&gt;`.

This is an example of [HTML character entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

Comment: Mostly just trivia, but: technically only the '<' characters need to be escaped, and not the '>' ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally doable by using HTML Entities. There is a set of certain characters that are reserved for a special use, and therefore, if you want to render them as they are, they would need to be plugged in differently - through the use of **entity name** or **entity number**.

```
&entity_name;
&#entity_number;
```

In your case, the characters that need to be rendered are '<' (**l**ess **t**han) and '>' (**g**reater **t**han). Their entity names are quite easy to remember - take the initials from their actual names. The reason for using entity numbers might be that not all of the browsers can sometimes support entity names, but they would support entity numbers.

```
<   less than       &lt;    &#60;
>   greater than    &gt;    &#62;
```

For more information, refer to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).